# Reshaping a mesh so its perimeter matches a closed curve

Tags: mesh

I have a surface mesh (an stl file, grey region in the figure) and a curve (an obj file, orange curve in the figure) imported in Blender from Rhino. What I'm trying to do is, I want to reshape the mesh so its perimeter will fit the curve exactly. Remeshing is not an option for me. I have to keep all the vertices and connectivity the same. I don't have any experiences with Blender but I saw some videos over Youtube where people were shaping meshes with Bezier curves. I thought I could do my task too, but I might be wrong. I'm sorry if my question is unrelated or unclear but I can provide more details if you need. I'd really appreciate it if you could give me a pointer.

Thank you,

Edit: Can I try to create a surface using the curve and map the mesh on the new surface?

[image: Mesh and the curve]

Comment: Maybe look into Knife Project tool?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this precisely, you'd likely have to eyeball it, but it will probably involve some manual work. I suppose it is not a simple scale operation.

Comment: Thank you all, for your comments. Unfortunately I have to have a precise match. I'll take a look into Knife Project. And yes, the feature of the curve that I try to fit is totally different.